# Maven - Generate getting failed

Tags: java, maven

Helllo,

I am trying to execute the below command in mvn

```
mvn -X archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.servicemix.tooling -DarchetypeArtifactId=servicemix-cxf-code-first-osgi-bundle -DarchetypeVersion=2012.01.0.redhat-60024 -DgroupId=org.fusesource.example -DartifactId=cxf-basic -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

While doing so, getting the below error

```
3626 [main] [ERROR] org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to redhat-techpreview-all-repository (http:// maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/): Access denied to: http: // maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.4/maven-archetype-plugin-2.4.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:2.4
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to redhat-techpreview-all-repository (http:// maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/): Access denied to: http:// maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.4/maven-archetype-plugin-2.4.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to redhat-techpreview-all-repository (http:// maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/): Access denied to: http:// maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.4/maven-archetype-plugin-2.4.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
```

At first, I thought its due to the proxy settings. But its not the case. I even overrided the proxy with the options `-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=10.142.125.36 -DproxyPort=8080`

Could you please help to resolve the issue?

Thanks and regards
Novice

Answer (score 0):

Your maven client can't access repo1.maven.org. I think there's still something wrong with your settings.xml.

Try to find `conf/settings.xml` and make changes like in below  ;

```
<proxy>
<id>optional</id>
<active>true</active>
<protocol>http</protocol>
<host>Your proxy host</host>
<port>proxy host ip</port>
<nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```